# Нужно поменять алгоритм обходу в ширину в алгоритм обходу в глубину

Tags: java, алгоритм, поиск

Есть метод который ищет файлы в операционной систему, он реализован на алгоритме поиска в ширину. Помогите переделать его на алгоритм поиска в глубину.

```
/**
     * @param parent - каталог внутри которго находятся файлы и папки.
     * @return
     */
    private static Iterable<File> getFileAsList(String parent) {
        ArrayList<File> result = new ArrayList<>();
        Deque<File> filesList = new ArrayDeque<>();
        filesList.offer(new File(parent));
        File temp;
        while (!filesList.isEmpty()) {
            temp = filesList.pollFirst();
            if (temp.isDirectory()) {
                filesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(temp.listFiles()));
            } else {
                System.out.println(temp.toString());
                result.add(temp);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

вот результат работы метода:

C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory1\file.txt
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory2\file1234.exe
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory2\oneLevel\file123.exe
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory4\oneLevel\fileOne.exe
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory4\oneLevel\fileTwo.exe
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory2\oneLevel\twoLevel\file.exe
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory3\oneLevel\twoLevel\file.txt
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory5\oneLevel\twoLevel\file.txt
C:\Users\Sanek\AppData\Local\Temp\testFolderForJava\testDirectory6\oneLevel\twoLevel\threeLevel\file.exe

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае, скорее всего будет достаточным поменять структуру данных для `filesList`. В поиске в глубину это будет стек:

```
     Stack<File> filesList = ...
```

Comment: Можно оставить тот же дек, но добавлять и снимать с одного конца - например, `temp = filesList.pollLast();`